# How can I disable bounce effect in Scrollview (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have used Scrollview in my screen and when I log y offset I get negative values?

How can I disable Scrollview bouncing?

Answer (score 26):

This code should worked:

```
<ScrollView
    alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
    alwaysBounceVertical={false}
    bounces={false}
/>
```

Comment: Accordingly oficial react native documentation this properties use for just IOS, but how about Android? Any ideas how to disable bounce there?

Comment: @jocoders, check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76123813/5804328

Answer (score 11):

set this:

```
<ScrollView bounces={false}>
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers given by others only solve the issue for iOS, but for Android, the issue still persists.

Here is the final solution I found after some digging.

Solution for iOS: (https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#bounces-ios)

```
<ScrollView
    alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
    alwaysBounceVertical={false}
    bounces={false}
/>
```

Solution for Android: (https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#overscrollmode-android)

```
<ScrollView
    overScrollMode="never"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are props called `alwaysBounceVertical`. Set it to false.

```js
<ScrollView
    alwaysBounceVertical={false}
/>
```

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#alwaysbouncevertical) is doc.

Comment: Yes. It work with ios. Can you please post your code that you have done ?

Comment: `<ScrollView 
     style={styles.content}
     scrollEventThrottle={16}
     alwaysBounceVertical={false}
     onScroll={Animated.event(
           [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollYAnimatedValue } } }],
           { listener: (event) => this._handleScroll(event) }
     )}>`

Comment: After adding this `alwaysBounceVertical={false}`,  scrollview still bouncing ?

Comment: So, may be this problem is by your `onScroll` . It should be `onScroll={() => { // your code }}`